# Using 1 KEYWORD in SFMC to loop questions

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am trying to create my own "Info Capture" process in Mobile Connect.  Everything works, except for when I try to put in a termination of the conversation (reached the end).

```
  IF @end THEN
    EndSMSConversation(######, MOBILE_NUMBER)
  ELSE
    SetSmsConversationNextKeyword(######, MOBILE_NUMBER, "QUESTION")
  ENDIF
```

When I put this in and run it, I get an error message.  However, if I remove all but the Set, it works correctly.  What is weird is that when I view it in the edit box the first ###### is highlighted. It is almost like the code is being evaluated holistically and not just linearly.

Does anyone have any tips to do something like this? Ultimately trying to capture data in my own DE, not burn a lot of keywords, and have unlimited support.

Comment: For the time being, I ended up making the EndSmsConversation a separate/global end keyword, and then just use the IF to assign a variable to use in the Set.  Not ideal, but I believe this is the only current solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `EndSMSConversation` AMPscript function cannot be used in conversation-based templates such as Double Opt-In, Vote/Survey or Info Capture messages. You will need to use a Text Response template instead.